# Laravel: decode JSON to Blade view

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a DB table called `pages`. There is a column `section_ids` where I store a JSON array of all section ids that are enabled to the corresponding page. The array looks like this:

```
{'1','3','4','5','6','7'}
```

In my controller `HomePageController` I have the following:

```
public function index() {        
    $sections = json_encode($this->getHomepageSections());
    return view('homepage', compact('sections'));
}

public function getHomepageSections() {
    return $sections = Page::select('section_ids')->where('name', 'home')->get();
}
```

And this is `Page` model:

```
public function sections() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Section');
}
```

All I want to do is to get every section id from the JSON string and:

1. get it's contents
2. display it in the blade view by `@include('sections.filename')`

P.S. I hope I described it clearly, cause I have some issues with that for now :)

Comment: You probably need to read the relation section on the laravel Eloquent ORM docs, once more. The ids should not be stored as json. Each row should has its own row. This way you can use relations the way you are trying now. This way it aint going to work. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent  if you are looking for something more comprehensive... see laracast https://laracasts.com/series/eloquent-relationships which might be easyer to understand when just starting with laravel

Comment: Well, just ran through some relations and found out that Many To Many is the one I needed! Thanks for a tip, @DannyEbbers